# set where statement when or if variable is not null

Tags: sql-server

I declare a variable:

```
declare @Type nvarchar(max);
```

Then I wanna write a statement and use `@Type` when it is `not null`:

```
select * from Table1
where IsUsed = 1
if @Type is not 
  and UserId in select UserId in UserTable
```

this is wrong statement, how should i do for this problem?

---

this statement is : when @Type is null then don't care about UserId (select all UserId), but if @Type is not null then select some UserId from another Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from Table1
where IsUsed = 1
and 
(
     @Type is null 
     or UserId in (select UserId in UserTable)
)
```

Comment: Please note that he wants the `@Type`, `not` being null

Comment: i tried your statement a lot of times, and it works perfect, thx

Comment: @Kiril: Yes, my query handles exact that condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from Table1 a
left join UserTable b
    on a.UserId = b.UserId
where IsUsed = 1
    and (@type is not null and b.UserId is not null)
```

But in reality, you should have a FK on the UserId so that you wouldn't have to do that sort of existence check.